# I don't understand Hanoi algorithm

Tags: c, recursion

Let's be honest: I've been doing good in programming since the beginning of the year (high school senior high school) until the day we finally saw recursion.
I don't understand the recursive code of Hanoi Towers: the specific point in it that i don't seem to get is the switch between the destination tower and origin and vice versa:

I basically understand what recursion is, and what a stack is, but I don't understand why the order of the towers is changed.

Your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you.
//N number of pieces

```
    private void Déplacer(short N, string o, string i, string d)
    {
        if (N == 1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Move " + o + "to " + d);
            lstUn.Items.Add((lstUn.Items.Count + 1).ToString() + "-" + "Move " + o + " vers " + d);
            return;
        }


        else
        { 
        //Switch d and i
            Déplacer((short)(N - 1), o, d, i);
            lstUn.Items.Add((lstUn.Items.Count + 1).ToString() + "-" + "Déplace " + o + " vers " + d);
            MessageBox.Show("Déplace " + o + " vers " + d); //1 vers 3
            Déplacer((short)(N - 1), i, o, d);

        }
```

Comment: ...And is this homework?

Comment: If this is C, the use of the glyph 'é' in a function name is exotic.

Comment: Have you actually done the tower of hanoi puzzle for real? If everything starts on the middle stack and you want to move it then you make a stack of one item on the left. Then a stack of two items on the right and then a stack of three items on the left and so on. Essentially you have to use the free space which moves each iteration. I've not followed your code carefully but this is likely to be the explanation (in rough at least).

Comment: The reason for choosing the towers of Hanoi as a CS introduction is that you can do them by hand. I've understood them back then by getting a roll of cookies and playing Hanoi with them. And eating them afterwards, but that's besides the point. I'd like to give you the same advice: Perform the algorithm with cookies first, then with code.

Comment: Also see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution which explains it all.

Comment: @thiton, cookies, this is funny... never though about; when i was 6 i got a toy puzzle w/ 7 disks; it was quite a nice feat, truly lovable... but also scary when i read about a bigger version of the tower and the end of the world coming when it gets solved.

Answer (score 3):

The order of the towers is changed because the two recursive steps have different purposes.  For one of them, the purpose is "move entire stack from tower A to tower C" (goal #1).  For the other, the purpose is "move the bottom ring from tower A to tower C by putting all of the *other* rings on tower B" (goal #2).

It's probably easiest to understand if you look at an example with 3 rings.  Initially we have:

```
A (3)(2)(1)
B
C
```

We want to move the rings from A to C, but to do that we  first need to put the bottom ring on C.  Thus, we start with goal #2.  In goal #2, we need to move all of the *other* rings onto B, thus when stepping into it we get goal #1 but with the destination tower changed to B.  Once done, we get:

```
A
B (2)(1)
C (3)
```

Now We have goal #1 from B to C.  But to do this, we first have goal #2 from B to C (which is essentially goal #1 from B to A).  So, basically, the destination tower changes because with each recursive step we're switching between goal #1 and goal #2.

Answer (score 2):

Under the rules of the Tower of Hanoi, you can never put a bigger disk on top of a smaller one.

Imagine three towers, with tower 1 have three disks on it.  To move the three disks to tower 3, you need to be able to move the biggest disk from tower 1 to tower 3; that means you have to move the two smaller disks from tower 1 to tower 2.  How do you move the two disks from tower 1 to tower 2?  Well, you need to move disk 1 to tower 3; then you can move disk 2 to tower 2; then you can move disk 1 from tower 3 to tower 2.  Now you can move disk 3 to tower 3; and you need to move the two disks from tower 2 to tower 3 - which means you move disk 1 to tower 1; then disk 2 to tower 3; and finally disk 1 to tower 3, completing the process.

And that is the essence of the algorithm.  Each time you need to move some number of disks from one tower to another, you recurse.

A consequence of the rules is that the smallest disk is moved every other step.

Answer (score 2):

A great explanation for the algorithm can be found  in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution

Notice how the code is almost a line to line  implementation of this algorithm